# Angular-ui-router: Making asynchronous call across state transition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I'm trying to make an asynchronous API call triggered by the onEnter to a new .state

```
onEnter: function(StatFactory){ 
                StatFactory.getStats(function(res){
                    console.log("callback");
            });
    }
```

what I've noticed so far is that it calls the async function first, then instantiates the controller for the new state and finally fires the callback.

The function will update data inside the factory, but the $scope won't be updated.

I thought maybe I need to force $apply on the new $scope, but I don't know how.

Any idea? (I'm a novice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `onEnter` does not provide you with a `$scope` to bind the results to.

You can either call the function upon controller creation (IE controller's definition block) or use the `resolve` state param (note: this will cause the state to not be activated if the asynchronous function fails).

Here's an example with `resolve`:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
 ...
 //Will wait for the getStats call to end. You can inject the stats to the controller now.
 resolve: {
  stats: function(StatFactory) { return  StatFactory.getStats(); }
 },
 controller: function($scope, stats){
  //Use stats
  $scope.stats = stats;
 }
});
```

Comment: thanks Muli, both solution are great. After I got deeper into promises and two-way data binding I can say my question sounded a bit silly.